# Likelihood ratio test for the uniform distribution

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Suppose that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are iid random variables having the uniform distribution on $[0,\theta]$, $\theta>0$, with the density given by
$$
 f(x)=
 \begin{cases}
 \frac1\theta&\text{for}\ 0\le x\le\theta,\\
 0&\text{for}\ x<0\ \text{or}\ x>\theta.
 \end{cases}
$$
Consider testing $H_0:\theta\le\theta_0$ versus $H_1:\theta>\theta_0$. Denote $x_{(n)}=\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$. The likelihood function is given by
$$
L(\theta\mid\mathbf x)=
\begin{cases}
\theta^{-n}&\text{if}\ \theta\ge x_{(n)},\\
0&\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Since $\sup_{0<\theta\le\theta_0}L(\theta\mid\mathbf x)=0$ if $\theta_0<x_{(n)}$ and $x_{(n)}^{-n}$ otherwise, it seems that the likelihood ratio test (LRT) statistic is given by
$$
\lambda(\mathbf x)
=\frac{\sup_{0<\theta\le\theta_0}L(\theta\mid\mathbf x)}{\sup_{\theta>0}L(\theta\mid\mathbf x)}
=
\begin{cases}
0&\text{if}\ x_{(n)}>\theta_0,\\
1&\text{if}\ x_{(n)}\le\theta_0.
\end{cases}
$$
The LRT has the rejection region of the form $\{\pmb x:\lambda(\pmb x)\le c\}$ with some $0\le c\le 1$. But then it seems that the LRT only rejects $H_0$ when $x_{(n)}>\theta_0$. Since this would never happen if $H_0$ is true, the size of the LRT is $0$.

> Is the size of the LRT $0$? Is this true? Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: what is the size of the LRT? what is the definition of size here? your analysis seems correct to me

Comment: @DanielS. The size is the supremum of the probabilities of incorrectly rejecting $H_0$.

Comment: yes, I think you will never incorrectly reject the null hypothesis, because you will only reject if you are sure that you should -- otherwise, it is better to stick to the simpler hypothesis (like in Occam's Razor?)

Comment: would this result hold for any set of hypothesis for which the support of one is contained in the other? given hypothesis with corresponding bounded supports?

Comment: Is you want an LRT at level $\alpha$, use the randomized test $\phi=\mathbf1_{x_{(n)}>\theta_0}+\alpha\mathbf1_{x_{(n)}\le \theta_0}$. Not surprisingly, this test (which has size $\alpha$) is also a UMP test for testing $H_0$ against $H_1$.